# Where can I find linux-kernel-headers-x.x.x.x for SUSE?

Tags: linux, vmware, linux-kernel, suse

I'm installing VMware Workstation on a SLED 11 SP1, and the installation is blocked by an error message "Kernel headers for version 2.6.32.27-0.2-default were not found". If you installed them in a non-default path you can specify the path below. Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions and click Refresh to search again in default locations.

The output of rpm -qa | grep kernel is

```
kernel-default-2.6.32.27-0.2.2
kernel-default-base-2.6.32.27-0.2.2
linux-kernel-headers-2.6.32-1.4.13
kernel-default-extra-2.6.32.27-0.2.2
nfs-kernel-server-1.2.1-2.10.1
```

I had met this issue in Ubuntu and I installed the required linux header via apt-get then the issue disappeared. But in SLED, I didn't find the rpm package in SUSE's software repository, and I also google "linux-kernel-headers-2.6.32.27" but did not match any documents.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

The output result of zypper se kernel | grep kernel is

```
i | linux-kernel-headers | Linux Kernel Headers                                            | package   
  | linux-kernel-headers | Linux Kernel Headers                                            | srcpackage
```

Comment: Good question! Still without straightforward answer

Answer (score 7):

The kernel-header error is misleading - you have to install **kernel-source**. (After you do that, you might have to update the kernel itself, so check that afterwards.)

Comment: Actually isn't it kernel-devel?

Comment: Well, where I saw the issue discussed, it said to install kernel-source, and that worked. one of the places: [one vmtools discussion](http://www.jorink.nl/2010/10/install-vmware-tools-under-sles-11-sp1/) I can't speak to kernel-devel. Color me clueless.

Comment: also [here] (http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/405220-installing-vmware-tools.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
yast2 -i kernel-source
```

Comment: OP just wants the headers, presumably (I'm not familiar with SUSE) the command is `yast2 -i kernel-headers-x.x.x.x` (including the version is critical, otherwise they just get the latest).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide output result from `zypper se kernel | grep header`

Problem here is that your SUSE installed kernel headers is **linux-kernel-headers-2.6.32-1.4.13** which doesn't match your current kernel **2.6.32.27**

First, uninstalling package **linux-kernel-headers-2.6.32-1.4.13** 
`#rpm -e linux-kernel-headers-2.6.32-1.4.13`

Update repositories with `#zypper ref`

Check for kernel headers package **Version**, `#zypper if linux-kernel-headers | grep Version`

if it match **2.6.32.27**, so just go ahead.

Hope this help,

Comment: sudo zypper if linux-kernel-headers | grep Version
Version: 2.6.32-1.4.13
it doesn't match 2.6.32.27, it looks like I should downgrade the 2.6.32.27 kernel to 2.6.32-1.4, right?

Comment: I tried to use "zypper udpate linux-kernel-headers" to update the headers, but got "No update candidate for 'linux-kernel-headers'."

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include
ln -s   generated/uapi/linux/ .
```

Apparently `version.h` is not quite where VMWare expects it.   VMWare finds it via the softlink.

Answer (score 0):

With Opensuse 12.3, I had to run it has a root user.

I right click on the start button ( like if it were the Windows Start Menu ) then clicked "Edit Applications and under Systems > More Programs Selected VMware Workstation then went to "Advance"tab and checked the box run as a different user and wrote root.

Then do this on a terminal
[CODE] cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include
ln -s   generated/uapi/linux/ [/CODE]

Answer (score 0):

For me, after install "kernel-source", **restart** vmware, then vmware will auto detect the headers location.