# Open SUSE missing kernel-devel headers

Tags: linux, kernel, backlight

I am trying to make a custom API for maintaining the backlight of the computer, however, as the examples suggest, the "backlight.h" is to be included, and there is no such a file on my Open SUSE distro. I`ve installed kernel-devel package, and kernel-source, however nothing. Also I need more libs like "gpio.h" and "driver.h". So why I don`t have them?

Comment: and what about `kernel-headers` package?

Comment: "zypper search kernel-headers", gives me no results found.

Comment: It`s also said that the headers are in "linux-glibc-devel" package, which I have.

Comment: ah, okay, I am on Ubuntu / CentOS. Maybe [this will help you further](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/491320-kernel-header-install/page2?s=b66ce0dda9c25d3ad4e2c489ba5c3547) -> `And I also install the "kernel-syms" package, which brings in the headers as a dependency`

Comment: Yes, I just did that, however, the headers are still missing. Can you check if your distro has them?

Comment: on CentOS 7 - `yum install kernel-headers.x86_64` - when I use the tab expansion. Currently I have no SuSe VM (and as told before I am on Ubuntu/CentOS)

Comment: Too bad... I still don`t have them ...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/245544/where-can-i-find-linux-kernel-headers-x-x-x-x-for-suse?rq=1

I`ve checked this topic, and even this did not work for me?

Comment: maybe just download [backlight.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/backlight.h), [gpio.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/gpio.h), [driver.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/gpio/driver.h) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
zypper se kernel | grep header
```

Most likely then you can see what packages do you have to install

Comment: Hello, the command you proposed gives me gives me no output :)